# Regular Expression - Starting and ending with, and contains specific string in the middle

Tags: regex

I would like to generate a regex with the following condition:

The string "EVENT" is contained within a xml tag called "SHEM-HAKOVETZ".

For example, the following string should be a match:

```
<SHEM-HAKOVETZ>104000514813450EVENTS0001dfd0.DAT</SHEM-HAKOVETZ>
```

Comment: `(?<=<SHEM-HAKOVETZ>).*(?=</SHEM-HAKOVETZ>)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this `^<SHEM-HAKOVETZ>.*EVENT.*<\/SHEM-HAKOVETZ>$`

Answer (score 0):

**Regular expression**

`^<SHEM-HAKOVETZ>.*EVENTS.*<\/SHEM-HAKOVETZ>$`

**Parts of the regular expression**

`^` From the beginning of the line

`<SHEM-HAKOVETZ>` Starting tag

`.*` Any character - zero or more

`EVENT` Middle part

`<\/SHEM-HAKOVETZ>$` Ending part of the match

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/U7owIX/1) is the working regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match this line, you could use this regex:

```
<SHEM-HAKOVETZ>*EVENTS.*(?=<\/SHEM-HAKOVETZ>)
```

However, I would not recommend using regex XML-based data, because there may be problems with whitespace handling in XML (see [this article](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/wang-whitespace-092897.html) for more information). I would suggest using an actual XML parser (and then applying the reg to be sure about your results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to only match the "value" part ignoring the XML tags:

```
(?<=<SHEM-HAKOVETZ>)(?:.*EVENTS.*)(?=<\/SHEM-HAKOVETZ>)
```

You can check it out in action at: https://regex101.com/r/4XiRch/1
It works with Lookbehind and Lookahead to make sure it will only match if the tags are correct, but for further coding will only match the content.